# Ionic User Push token

Tags: ionic-framework, token

I want to add a device token to an user in my app. I have the device token, I have the user, but I cant add the token to the user despite read a lot of documentation about the issue.

Anyone can help me please?

Here is my code, thanks

```
var io = Ionic.io();



    username = localStorage.getItem('username');


    var signupSuccess = function(user) {
      // user was authenticated, you can get the authenticated user

      console.log(user);

    };

    var signupFailure = function(errors) {
      for (var err in errors) {
        // check the error and provide an appropriate message
        // for your application
        console.log(err);
        user = Ionic.User.current();
        console.log(user);
      }
    };
    var details = {

      'email': 'email@gmail.com',
      'password': 'pass2',
      'username':'username'
    }


    Ionic.Auth.signup(details).then(signupSuccess, signupFailure);

    var push = new Ionic.Push();
    var user = Ionic.User.current();
    console.log('USER',user);

    var callback = function(pushToken) {


      console.log('Registered tokens:', pushToken.token);

      alert('TOKEN: '+pushToken.token);

      user.addPushToken(pushToken);

      user.save(); // you NEED to call a save after you add the token

    }

    push.register(callback);
```

Comment: Sorry  i am not getting your question

Comment: I want to add a device token to an ionic user. I can get the device token and I cant create an user but I cant fetch the user and the token. My question is how I can do this.